# How to access higher resolutions in windows 11 virtualBox7 guest os under Ubuntu 22

Tags: virtualbox, screenresolution

My display resolution is locked to 1024x1024 running virtualbox7 with guest OS windows 11.  I tried Devices -> Insert Guest  additions
That launches a windows to Download the Guest  additions which fails.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://www.oracle.com/virtualization/technologies/vm/downloads/virtualbox-downloads.html and download the https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/7.0.8/VBoxGuestAdditions_7.0.8.iso or whatever shows up under "VBox GuestAdditons".

Then start the Guest OS and from
Devices -> Optical Drives select the guest additions iso you just downloaded and run the autorun CD or run VBoxWindowsAdditions manually.

You will notice that your screen flashes during the installation.